# complexity of a function that depends on n%3

Tags: time-complexity

```
T(1)=1
Func_two (n,b)
1) if (n=0)
2)   then return 1
3) else if (n=1)
4)   then return b
5) else if (mod(n,3)==0)
6)   then return Func_two(n/3,b)
7) else
8)   return b*Func_two(n-1,b)
```

How do I calculate this?

I see that $\mathcal{O}(\log(n))\le T(n) \le \mathcal{O}(n)$ because either we decrease by $1 $ all the time or by $\frac{n}{3}$.

Also dividing gets us much closer to $T(1) $ then reducing by $1 $ so I assume the solution is $ T(n)=\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$.

Got stuck trying to prove this with induction, can't even reach the $T(n) $ reccurence  formula from the given pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $n$ in the ternary base. If the lowest order digit (trit) is a $1$ or a $2$, $T$ is called once or twice and $n$ becomes a multiple of $3$. Then the last digit (now a zero) is dropped.

Hence, the total number of calls equals the sum of the trits of $n$ plus the number of trits.

E.g. $n=43_d=1121_t\to1+1+2+1+4$ calls.

You can also observe that the number of multiplies is the number of trits. The function returns $b$ to the power equal to the sum of the trits, here $b^5$.

---

Note that the number of trits is given by

$$\lfloor\log_3n\rfloor+1$$

so that the number of calls varies between $\lfloor\log_3n\rfloor+1$ and $3\lfloor\log_3n\rfloor+3$.

Comment: understood, thank you very much!
Is there a way to find $T(n) $ as a function though, or only upper and lower bounds?

Comment: @DannyBlozrov: I gave the function, though you didn't notice...

Comment: $ T\left(n\right)=\log_{3}\left(n\right)+1+\sum_{i=0}^{i=\log_{3}\left(n\right)}\left(\frac{n}{3^{i}}-\left\lfloor \frac{n}{3^{i}}\right\rfloor \right) $ not too experienced with different bases but this seems to fit,since each trit is just the remainder of $\frac{n}{3} $ and then we just sum them

Comment: @DannyBlozrov: no, check your formula with $43$ and see...